# How do I clear and replace a collection in a one-to-many relationship in Grails/Groovy

Tags: grails, grails-orm

This question is in two parts, first part is about clearing a list and second part is about assigning an owner to an object.

I have a one-to-many relationship between two domain objects in my model in Grails.  The relationship looks like this...

```
class Person {

    static hasMany = [authorities: Role, locations: Location]
}

class Location {

    static belongsTo = Person

}
```

In my app the `locations` list on `Person` gets completely refreshed and replaced with a new list on a user action.  What's more I get the list of `Location` objects independent of the associated `Person`.  I resolve which person to apply them to by retrieving the currently logged in user, which I call `activePerson` and is fine for my purposes.

What I want to do is delete all the existing locations on `activePerson` and insert all the new ones, associating them with the `activePerson` as I go.  I have a bunch of properties on `Person` which I don't want to persist at this point, so I want to avoid saving the whole parent object just because locations children have changed.

I thought of iterating throught the `activePerson.locations` list and deleting them one by one and relying on GORM/Hibernate to batch the queries together and flush at the end.  This seems like brute force, although it might work.  I was expecting there to be a `clearLocations` method or something similar, but I can't find one.

If I do just replace the `activePerson.locations` with a new list and call `activePerson.save(flush:true)`, will GORM handle the delete of the existing rows?

Secondly I want to put the new `Location` objects onto `activePerson`.  Again I could populate the `activePerson.locations` and save the whole thing, but I would like to avoid that if I can.  I can save them individually, but how do I set `belongsTo` on each `Location` object as I go?

So to recap:

1. How do I clear a list at the many end of a one-to-many collection?
2. How do I associate independent objects with a parent object and persist them individually?

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Clearing `Collection` approach didn't worked for me:

```
activePerson.locations.clear()
```

Just try iterate over collection with avoiding `ConcurrentModificationException` by calling `collect()`:

```
activePerson.locations.collect().each {
    item.removeFromLocations(it)
}
```

And after that save the entity to execute SQL statement:

```
activePerson.save flush:true
```

---

Link to article to read more:
http://spring.io/blog/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/

Comment: it didn't work for me until I specified orphanRemoval=true on the Entity
@OneToMany(..., orphanRemoval=true)

Comment: Shouldn't 'item' be 'activePerson'? So that way we can call removeFromLocations(it)?

Answer (score 10):

For #1 you can clear the collection (it's a Set by default):

```
activePerson.locations.clear()
```

For #2 use addToLocations:

```
activePerson.addToLocations(location)
```

and when you save the person the location<->person relationship will be updated.

Comment: @Burt, thanks (again) for your answer, I owe you a beer.  This does however imply I have to persist the Person object, which I was trying to avoid.  Is there a sensible alternative or should I just live with updating a record which hasn't really changed?

Comment: In addition to Burt's answer, you may need to implement equals and hashcode on the collection object, and specify cascade: "all-delete-orphan" on the mapping of the collection.

Comment: `activePerson.locations.clear()` on the collection wont work. Try: `activePerson.locations.collect().each { item.removeFromLocations(it) }`

Comment: What if I have defined a join table between the two domain classes like this: Class Person_Location { Person person; Location location; int customField; }? what kind of cascade do I need to define to use the clear the collection of locations? Notice that, in my case, I do not have the belongsTo in Location class

Answer (score 8):

While this is an older question, I ran into a very similar situation in which I wanted to update a set of child records.  Here's how I chose to resolve it.  For simplicity, I'll use the same object/relation names as the asker of the question.

1. In the `mapping` block of the parent domain, add:

   ```
   static mapping = {
       locations(cascade: "all-delete-orphan")
   }
   ```
2. In the child domain, add the `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotation (just in case there's another one lurking about, I'm referring to `groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode`).
3. Add all of the children elements to the parent domain using the Grails `addTo` methods (e.g. `addToLocations`) and then save the parent domain.

While this approach does require saving the parent domain (which the asker didn't want to do), it seems like it's the most appropriate approach given the clear `belongsTo` definition in the model.  I would therefore answer the asker's numbered questions like this:

1. Rather than doing it manually, let Grails/Hibernate clear the records by specifying the `all-delete-oprhan` cascade behavior on the relation.
2. Don't attempt to save the child records directly, but instead save the parent object to match what Grails seems to expect.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works for me:

```
activePerson.locations.clear()
activePerson.properties = params

...

activePerson.save()
```

This clears the set of locations, then adds back just the ones currently selected in params.