# Grails Hibernate simple example but gives StaleObjectStateException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, grails

I have a borderline textbook example of relationship. Company hasMany WorkPlace and Workplace belongs to a Company.

In integration test I create Company object, add 3 workplaces to it. I use removeFromWorkplaces to remove them from Company object so I can delete them.

Funny thing, the first workplace I try to delete will be deleted, but the second one will explode with org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException:[...] org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)

Literally have no clue whats going on since the example is so simple and my other tests work well.

```
workplace1.delete() //OK
workplace2.delete() //exception
```

These guys share the same Company object.
No idea where to go from here.

Comment: Please post the test case.

Comment: Read through this link, http://stackoverflow.com/q/2072705/2889156 , It will of some help..

Comment: Added the cascade 'all-delete-orphans', didn't work. They don't get deleted.

Still get an exception after trying to delete the second instance ( the first one always work)

Comment: Additionally: tried it out on more examples, always the same. I remove the objects using parent.removeFrom***(child) and then child.delete(). First object will always be deleted, second one will explode with exception, not sure whats going on